# Rails 3.1 Unobtrusive Javascript with Flot

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, flot, unobtrusive-javascript

All,

I am using the Flot graphing library in my rails application.  I currently have a page working as expected, however all of the javascript for putting together the flot graph is inline in my "view".html.erb file.

Is there an easy way to move the static part of the javascript to an external file, generate the dynamic data as regular in the view/controller, and pass it to the javascript file? (through "data-message"??)

The basic layout looks like this:

Controller:

```
@portfolios = # a bunch of portfolios
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // show & hide some stuff
  var options = {
   .......
  };

// THIS IS THE DYNAMIC PORTION

var portfolio_collection = []
var id_lookup = []

<% @portfolios.each do |portfolio| %>
  <% attribute1 = portfolio.attribute1 %>
  <% attribute2 = portfolio.attribute2 %>
  portfolio_collection.push([<%= attribute1 %>,<%= attribute2 %>]);
  id_lookup.push([<%= portfolio.id %>]);
<% end %>

// END DYNAMIC

var plot = $.plot(  // This is the plot command, puts graph in #select div
      $("#select"),
       [ { data: portfolio_collection, label: "Return"} ], 
       options
    );

// A SCHWACK OF JAVASCRIPT
........

</script>

<h1>My HTML content...</h1>

<br />
<div id="select" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
.... a bunch of other divs which renders javascript results from clicking on the graph ....
```

Comment: Oh well.. will leave it as-is I guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did to get around this issue, is move the flot script to the portfolios.js file.  Then I bound a click event to generate the flot graph.  In the anchortab I put something like this

```
<a id="generate" data-var="<%=@portfolo_data%>" data-var="<%=@portfolo_options%>">Generate Graph</a>
```

Then in the js file I pulled the call like this

```
$(function (){
    $("#generate").click( (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        eval("var data =" +  $("#generate").data("var") + ";");
        eval("var options =" + $("#generate").data("options") + ";");
        $.plot($("#select"), data, options);
    });
});
```

All that is left to do is build out the @portfolio_data and the @portfolio_options strings in the Portfolio Controller.

Comment: Sorry - I just saw this answer now.  Great!